# F# & COM api downcasting issue

Tags: f#, com, interop

I have some C# COM Api example that works but fails when translated to F#.

The F# code is :

```
let list = api.CreateXXX() :?> XXX
```

The C# conversion is implicit (the object defines the variable as XXX and then initializes it with api.CreateXxxModule()  without further conversion.

```
private XXX list;
[...]
list = api.CreateXXX()
```

> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'ThomsonReuters.Interop.RTX.AdxRtList'. This operation failed because
>   the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with
>   IID '{057B736E-03DF-11D4-99C8-00105AF7EDAD}' failed due to the
>   following error: Cette interface n’est pas prise en charge (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Using the XXXClass instead of XXX for the downcasting didn't work either :

> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to class type
>   'XXXClass'. COM components that enter
>   the CLR and do not support IProvideClassInfo or that do not have any
>   interop assembly registered will be wrapped in the __ComObject type.
>   Instances of this type cannot be cast to any other class; however they
>   can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component
>   supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Would anyone have used F# with COM Apis that are usually used with C# and have some tip on these type conversions ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/functions/do-bindings

Comment: @HansPassant that's just a link to `do` bindings...

Comment: It specifically talks about the attribute you have to use to support single-threaded COM servers.

Comment: @HansPassant it sure does :)

Comment: Hi, I can't mark you as the correct answer but it is, adding the STAThread attribute to the main function works. I'll update my question to reflect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding the STAThread attribute to the main function worked in :

```
module Main =

  [<STAThread>] 
  do
    ...
```